# Xpath Yahoo Finance

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, python-requests, lxml, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get data from Yahoo, primarily EV/EBITDA for stocks.

I tried using the xpath from chrome to get the text, which returned []; even after removing "tbody"

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics? 
p=')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
data = tree.xpath('//*[@id="Col1-0-KeyStatistics- 
Proxy"]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/text()')

print(data)
```

Again I have removed tbody and still get [] as a result.

I have been able to get some text back using the following.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
```

while 1:

```
tick = input('Type in stock ticker:  ')

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + tick + '/key-statistics?p=')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
data = tree.xpath('//*[@class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)"]/text()')

print('\n') 
print( tick + '-EV/EBITDA' + ':' +data[8])
print('\n')
pass
```

This works for most stocks, however since some stock are missing data the 9th value returned is not always EV/EBITDA. The web has the text "N/A" but the script has no place holder, so an empty field causes the data to move.

RESULTS:

```
Type in stock ticker:  AAPL


AAPL-EV/EBITDA:13.81


Type in stock ticker:  DRIO


DRIO-EV/EBITDA:-221.56%


Type in stock ticker:
```

DRIO lacks some data before EV/EBITDA therefore the wrong value is returned.

I need to either have the code above have place holders for N/A values.
OR
Properly get EV/EBITDA via preferebly xpath.

I am new to coding <1 month experience, self taught, be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Added a // instead of / before text()
this return N/A where there where N/A values instead of nothing so the 8th item in the list returned was ALWAYS EV/EBITDA, this also allows me to pull other data with ease for stocks.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

while 1:
tick = input('Type in stock ticker:  ')

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + tick + '/key-statistics?p=')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
data = tree.xpath('//*[@class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)"]//text()')

print('\n') 
print( tick)
print('Market Cap' + ': ' + data[0])
print('Enterprise Value' + ': ' + data[1])
print('P/E' + ': ' + data[2])
print('PEG' + ': ' + data[4])
print('P/S' + ': ' + data[5])
print('P/B' + ': ' + data[6])
print('EV/EBITDA' + ': ' + data[8])
print('\n')
pass
```

will return the following for ticker 'AAPL"

```
Type in stock ticker:  AAPl


AAPl
Market Cap: 1.05T
Enterprise Value: 1.09T
P/E: 19.74
PEG: 1.42
P/S: 4.12
P/B: 9.18
EV/EBITDA: 13.85


Type in stock ticker:
```